# Why does the server fail to send emails? SQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, email

As of the 23rd April 2014 the SQL Server Database Mail Log displayed this error:

The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 1 (2014-04-23T16:07:15). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Bad sequence of commands. The server response was: you must authenticate first (#5.5.1))

Everything was working fine the day before and no changes where made to the configuration of the Database Mail

Can any one explain why what could have happened in the space of one day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the configuration of the SMTP account that you are using to send mails. It's a common configuration problem.
Check this link:

[SQL SERVER – 2008 – Configure Database Mail – Send Email From SQL Database](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/)

Make sure that no one has changed the password of the SMTP account.